# Showcasing C++ CLI tool on the web

Tags: c++, command-line, web

I have some CLI tools that i want to showcase on the web.

I was thinking about a console which has the executable loaded.
Means you can do the same in your online console like in your OS console offline, just through the web.

Is there a software that already serves this use case?

Otherwise i am thinking about to build one myself.

Comment: How about a very simple PHP form which accepts parameters, passes them to the CLI program, captures it's output and displays it?

Comment: if anyone sees a similar usecase you can have a look at my implementation using nodejs and socketio https://github.com/haerrel/webconsole/